# Change the registration point of a video object

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation

Is there any way to change the registration of a video object (so that you can apply a tween effect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your video object in a movieclip and place where you want it to be registered in the clip (e.g.: top-left is `x=0`,`y=0`, center is `x=-video_obj.width/2`,`y=-video_obj.height/2`). Then, apply your tween effect to the containing movieclip.